# JMX connection using JMXMP hangs

Tags: jmx, jmxmp

I'm trying to establish a JMX connection to my tomcat instance from a java client using the below code.

```
JMXServiceURL url = new MXServiceURL("service:jmx:jmxmp://<host>:<port>"); //line 1
JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url);  //line 2
MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
```

Where

> host = remote machine where my tomcat instance is running
>
> port = jmx enabled port.  In my code it is 9840

My tomcat setenv.sh file is edited with below configurations to enable JMX

```
export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=9840 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false"
```

But, when i execute the program, it hangs at line 2.

If i change line 1 as 
`JMXServiceURL target = new JMXServiceURL("service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<host>:<port>/jmxrmi")` 
to use RMI instead of JMXMP it executes and i'm able to access various MX beans.

So, i'm not able connect if i use JMXMP protocal.  I'm able to connect if i use RMI protocol.  What might have went wrong when i use JMXMP?

Thanks,
nks

Answer (score 3):

In order to use the JMXMP client, you need to be running the [JMXMP Connector Server](http://dev.cs.uni-magdeburg.de/java/jdmk/api/javax/management/remote/jmxmp/JMXMPConnectorServer.html). It cannot connect to the [default] RMI Connector Server.

Also see this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34850410/add-jmxmp-listener-for-an-existing-java-application) for a JMXMP agent that you can install into a running server.

Comment: seems like tomcat does not have native support for JMXMP as per the thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11413178/how-to-enable-jmxmp-in-tomcat.  The thread suggests to create a 'LifecycleListener' to make tomcat JMXMP enable.  Is there any way to achieve this through some configuration entries as in the case JMX-RMI ?